# Maintain whitespace and line breaks in textarea transformed by CKEditor

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ckeditor

We're using CKEditor to transform a textarea, but it's failing to maintain the whitepsace / breaks in the pre-generated text.

We have tried a range of configurations, most recently:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textbox',{
        uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
        protectedSource: [/\r\n|\n|\r/gm]  
 });
```

However the browser doesn't like to regex -

```
Invalid regular expression: missing /
```

What is the correct way to get CKeditor to respect linebreaks / new lines in a textbox where the text is already generated?